# Do tears come out of eyes in a region with no gravity?

Tags: gravity

If a human start crying in a **zero gravity region**, will the tears come out from eyes or not?

Comment: OK, maybe I'm being kind of nit-picky here, but here is no such thing as a "zero gravity region." Astronauts in the space station, for example, are in a region where the gravity is almost as strong as the gravity here on Earth.  The difference is, the space station and the astronauts within it are in a perpetual state of _[free fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall)_. (More specifically, the astronauts and the space station are in _[orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit)_, which is a special case of free-fall.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a video of astronaut Chris Hadfield on the International Space Station simulating crying with a bottle of water. Essentially, without gravity to pull them downwards, the tears would pool around the eyes or stick to the cheeks of the crier.

https://youtu.be/P36xhtpw0Lg

Comment: Hadfield also has a great story about getting some contaminant in his eye during a spacewalk and being temporarily blinded the accumulated blob of tears --- in both eyes, since the tear-blob eventually crossed the bridge of his nose.  I seem to have heard this story [from his TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/chris_hadfield_what_i_learned_from_going_blind_in_space/transcript).

Answer (score 1):

If tears are formed, the will surely come out but will not accelerate in the downward direction, because there is no gravity.

Comment: this is also right as per https://youtu.be/P36xhtpw0Lg